# How to use Vercel KV to store and retrieve posts from a api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, vercel

How to use Vercel KV to store and retrieve posts from an API? I have a simple `node.js` express API that retrieves a random post from the `MongoDB` but how can I use Vercel KV to store and retrieve posts? like first it give normal `MongoDB` response to the user but after that it start giving response from Vercel KV from the cache..

```
router.get('/posts', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const page = Number(req.query.page) || 1; 
        const limit = Number(req.query.limit) || 50;
        const skip = (page - 1) * limit;
        const result = await User.aggregate([
            { $project: { posts: 1 } },
            { $unwind: '$posts' },
            { $project: { postImage: '$posts.post', date: '$posts.date' } },
            { $sort: { date: -1 } },
            { $skip: skip },
            { $limit: limit },
        ]);
        res.json(result);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error' });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[Vercel kv](https://vercel.com/docs/storage/vercel-kv) is a key value store with JSON extensions. It's different than a document-oriented database. Currently there is no such an option to do a search on stored json contents as far as I see.

However normalizing the data in the shape you want to do search may help you.

- Store the each post in a hash map
- Store a sorted set or list for each user, holds the keys of the posts

Let the post be something like this

```
const post = {id: "1234", user: "a-user", title: "dolor"}
```

We store it in this way

```
kv.hset(`post-${post.id}`, post)
```

Now we associate with the user

```
kv.sadd(`user-posts:${post.user}`, post.id)
```

If you want to get the posts of a user, you need to get them from that set.

```
kv.smembers(`user-posts:${post.user}`)
```

This will get you post IDs. You need to do `hgetall` query for all them.